# OpenGL problem using glTextureView on Framebuffer

Tags: opengl, glsl

i was trying to use textureview for framebuffer

it is ok using textureview that use base mipmap level, but when textureview specify mipmap level more that baselevel ,

glCheckFramebufferStatus() return error code 36057 that is incomplete_dimension

i checked there is no missmatching between textureivew and origintexture'size

here is code that is making prefilterCubemap for PBR Rendering

```
        unsigned int maxMipLevels = 5;
        for (int mip = 0; mip < maxMipLevels; ++mip)
        {
            unsigned int mipWidth = 128 * std::pow(0.5, mip);
            unsigned int mipHeight = 128 * std::pow(0.5, mip);
            RenderCommand::SetViewport(0, 0, mipWidth, mipHeight);

            m_DepthTexture->SetSize(mipWidth, mipHeight);
            CubeMapPass->DetachAll();
            CubeMapPass->AttachTexture(m_DepthTexture, AttachmentType::Depth_Stencil, TextureType::Texture2D, 0);

            float roughtness = (float)mip / (float)(maxMipLevels - 1);
            roughBuffer.roughtness = roughtness;
            roughnessConstantBuffer->SetData(&roughBuffer,sizeof(roughBuffer),0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                ....
                ...
                CameraBuffer.view = captureViews[i];
                cameraConstantBuffer->SetData(&CameraBuffer, sizeof(CameraData), 0);
                CubeMapPass->AttachTexture(m_PrefilterMap, AttachmentType::Color_0, TextureType::Texture2D, mip,i,1);
                CubeMapPass->Clear();
                ....
                ...

            }
        }
```

DepthStencil texture's size is changed for face texture of cubemap
based on mipmap(cubemap texture size starts at 128x128)

in AttachTexture Function

```
// m_RendererID is framebufferid
Ref<OpenGLRenderTargetView> targetview=CreateRef<OpenGLRenderTargetView>(type, texture, texture->GetDesc().Format, mipLevel, layerStart, layerLevel);
targetview->Bind(m_RendererID, attachType);
```

in texture view's bind function

```
GLenum attachmentIndex = Utils::GetAttachmentType(type);
GLenum target = Utils::GetTextureTarget(viewDesc.Type, multisampled);
glNamedFramebufferTexture(framebufferid, attachmentIndex, m_renderID, m_startMip);
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

as i said before there is no problem when textureview is accessing basemiplevel

but after first loop , textureview is accessing next mipmap (that textureSize will be 64x64, and depthStencilTexture size also 64x64)

and framebuffer has two attachment one is color(textureView) and other is depthstencil textrue

but glCheckFramebufferStatus keeps telling me there is incompletedimenssion after first loop..

i searched about textureview , https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage

in this article
glTextureView(..., GLuint minlevel​, GLuint numlevels​, GLuint minlayer​, GLuint numlayers​)

function will make textureview for origintexture and minlevel gonna be baselevel mipmap on textureview

as you can see my AttachTexture function it takes miplevel and next  parameter is for arraylevel and arraycount

and in creation textureview

```
glTextureView(m_renderID, target, srcTexID, internalformat, startMip, 1, startLayer, numlayer);
```

it only takes one mipmap not two or three

i dont know why it doesnt work..

and it works when im not using texture view
like below code

```
if (texture->GetDesc().Type == TextureType::TextureCube &&type == TextureType::Texture2D)
            {
                target = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + layerStart;
            }
            if (type == TextureType::TextureCube)
                glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentIndex, texId, mipLevel);
            else
                glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentIndex, target, texId, mipLevel);
            GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

Comment: "*glCheckFramebufferStatus() return error code 36057 that is incomplete_dimension*" That's not a thing. The error code number may be, but "incomplete_dimension" isn't something that FBOs fail to.

Comment: @Rabbid76 i changed code to generate 7 mimp but it doesnt solve problem ;(, when textureview is generated from origintexture that have 5mipmap , it doesnt return any error code .  thank you for replying me :)

Comment: `glNamedFramebufferTexture` and `glCheckFramebufferStatus` should not go together. One of them is a DSA function, while the other is not.

Comment: @Rabbid76: "*A texture with a size of 128x128 must have 7 mipmap levels (instead of 5) to be mipmap complete.*" That's not true. You can specify fewer than the maximum number of mipmaps, just as you can specify smaller than the maximum dimensions of a texture. This doesn't make it mipmap incomplete. In fact, if you use the `Storage` functions, it is *impossible* to create a mipmap incomplete texture.

Comment: @NicolBolas omg i taught error code 36057 is about FramebufferObject ,actually i found that error code on this site https://neslib.github.io/Ooogles.Net/html/0e1349ae-da69-6e5e-edd6-edd8523101f8.htm maybe it is wrong

Comment: I checked the XML spec files, and that error is for EXT_framebuffer_object. If you're using core FBO functions from 3.0 (let alone the 4.5 DSA stuff you're using), you should never be able to get that error.

Comment: @NicolBolas thank you for replying me :) im actually trying to find FBO function from 3.0..  does using core FBO function from 3.0 means that there is fbo function not from 3.0? i mean  like glCreateFramebuffers() that only support 4.5 , if i should use only from function from 4.5 is it possibe to binding framebuffer?